# Problems storing file in directory?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to store the picture that's taken but...

1. The file is created but the JPEG is empty.
2. I want to use the JPEG file to encode and send it to a server, because the bitmap is low definition for the use I want.

So how can I resolve these 2 problems?

```
public void takePicture() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Entra no takePicture",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("entra", "Take Picture");
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        photoFile = null;
        try {
            Log.d("entra","Vai criar file");
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.d("Erro",ex.getMessage());
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Entra no onActivityResult()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (requestCode ==  REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        image_BMP = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        bitmap.setImageBitmap(image_BMP);
        Log.d("Onactivity result()"," Passa aqui");
        myphoto= ImageUtility.getBytes(Bitmap.createBitmap(image_BMP));

    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"sai do onActivityResult()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public static File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name

    Log.d("entra", "Create File");
    String timeStamp = new   SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File pic = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + pic.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d("entra", "Create File");

    return pic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use and it works:

```
        Uri image = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(image,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Use inside onActivityResult instead of :

```
     Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    image_BMP = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    bitmap.setImageBitmap(image_BMP);
    Log.d("Onactivity result()"," Passa aqui");
    myphoto= ImageUtility.getBytes(Bitmap.createBitmap(image_BMP));
```

You don't have to create the file yourself. The camera will take care of it. You can delete the code for those things.

Edit:

To pass custom image location you can use this before you call startActivityForResult()

```
 Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(yourFile);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
```

Comment: The file location depends on the camera app you choose when it asks. For eg, my sony camera stores pics in the DCIM folder. The "filePath" variable will give you the location. You can pass this filePath to the upload function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you can set a custom location if needed. I use the above code in my app and it works beautifully

Answer (score 0):

```
intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
```

Add this line before startActivityforresult and store your path because sometimes the activity restarts and you will get a null pointer,

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);           
        outState.putString("imagePath", mCurrentPhotoPath);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // get the file path
        mCurrentPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString("imagePath");
    }
```

Then you can get the file from the path and you can upload file or You can read bitmap from file using

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(filePath))
```

Do as you wish with the bitmap thereafter

Comment: One Question Ravi, i'm trying to convert file to upload to a server and im using a function to convert to byte[] this function only receives a bitmap so do i need to pass the filepath is it ??

Comment: In other words i want to use Base64 to encode the original picture not the bitmap but i cant acess the location???

Comment: you can get the Bitmap using `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath))` then pass the bitmap to your method.